# Udev event and xrandr

Tags: kernel, xorg, udev

I am writing a UDEV rule to change the display settings  when the external monitor plugs-in or plugs-out. The rule is working perfectly fine.

Randomly, the script doesn' t work. After inspection, I found the following event is not happening upon device insertion/removal.

```
KERNEL[1382.370]  change  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0 (drm)
UDEV  [1385.939]  change  /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0 (drm)
```

Even if I wait for more than 60sec, the event is not happening. But as soon as I execute command **xrandr**, the event happens.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem.
I fixed it by adding `xrandr >/dev/null` before the first line in the script.

*I don't know why, but without it,
it's not working.*

Comment: This fixed the script for me too. Have you found out why this is the observed behavior in the meantime?